# How to avoid Java system properties on command line?

Tags: java, command-line, properties, system

I have a Java program and it uses `user.home` system property to get user home directory.
This program should not allow `user.home` property on command line. If user pass wrong directory from command line for user.home (java -Duser.home) then my program will have security hole.

So how can I restrict user.home from command line and it should uses only through program?

Comment: If your design depends on `user.home` to be correct for security, your program will be unsafe regardless of whether the user can specify it as a property on the command line.

Comment: If a user has access to another user's home directory, you have a potential security problem without running Java.

Comment: I'd suggest describing the reason `user.home` is security-sensitive in your use case, in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to guarantee that `user.home` is set correctly.

`user.home` is initialized from the `$HOME` environment variable if it isn't passed directly to the JVM.

It isn't possible to prevent a user from modifying their own environment.